# element auto hide auto append it in jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js

I use ajax post to query data in database, then add returned data to table.
But the data which I haved add, it has been auto hide. I want to it still show.

Here is my code:

```
        var str="";
        $.post("/queryproduct",
                {MaHang:$("#mahang").val().trim()},
                function(data,status){
                    if(data.length<=0){
                        alert("Không tìm thấy mã hàng "+$("#mahang").val().trim()+", bạn hãy vào phần quản lý hàng hóa để thêm loại hàng hóa này");
                    }else{
                        str="<tr>"+
                                    "<td>"+data[0].MaHang+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data[0].Quycach+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data[0].Trongluong+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data[0].Mota+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data[0].Theoong+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data[0].TheoKg+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+data[0].Theom+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+$("#soluong").val().trim()+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+$("#soluong").val()*data[0].Theom+"</td>"+
                                    "<td>"+"<a href='#' class='todo-remove' title='Xóa'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></a>"+"</td>"
                                "</tr>";
                    }
                    addelement(str);                        
            });
            function addelement(str){
                $("#list_product").find('tbody').append(str);
             }
```

Server code:

```
app.post('/queryproduct',function(req,res){
    var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM hanghoa WHERE MaHang=?",[input.MaHang],function(err,rows){
            if(err){
                //redirect
            }else{
                res.send(rows);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Can you help me solve this problem?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace your `addElement`-function to transform the `str` to a jQuery object, and then call `hide()`.

```
function addelement(str){
    var $element = $(str).hide();
    $("#list_product").find('tbody').append($element);
}
```

Comment: please review my question!